# OnTouchListener performs the draw after 3 click

Tags: android, touch-event

I have custom view and have override onTouchEvent in that customView class. I want to show three arcs on click of the customView. I have implemented below code to handle click event on that view.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

  if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 50, 500, 500);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 0, 45, true, p);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 145, 45, true, p);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 260, 45, true, p);
    invalidate(50, 50, 500, 500);
    return performClick();
  }
  return true;
}
```

Please suggest what mistake I have done.

Comment: What is the problem exactly?

Comment: the problem is he draws anything in onTouchEvent

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to call performClick() when click is already done?
You should return true if you had handled event or false otherwise. So i think corect variant should be

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

  if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    Paint p = new Paint();
    RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 50, 500, 500);
    p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 0, 45, true, p);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 145, 45, true, p);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 260, 45, true, p);
    invalidate(50, 50, 500, 500);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it draws after 3 clicks & its mentioned in title!!

Comment: wait, where did you initialized canvas variable? Can you show your onDraw method?

Comment: It draws the arcs on single click if it is done for MotionEvent.Action_Move.  :)